# How to get push notification (in json format) value in name value pair in onReceive() method

Tags: android

For Push Notification, we receive data in form of JSON from GCM.
What I want is to store the data in broadcast Receiver's ArrayList Method.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 
  String data=intent.getExtras().getString("notificationinfo");Log.d("notification.. ",data);
String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {sendNotification("Send error: " + intent.getExtras().toString());
  } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
 sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
     intent.getExtras().toString());
  } else {
   String message=intent.getString

Comment: How to get push notification(in json format) value in name value pair on onRecive method

Comment: It would be better if you could post your code in your question. Comment section is not the right place to add. It helps other to understand your problem in better way...

Comment: not working this code

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to get the Json repsonse in String format and then convert that string into json response in onReceive.

Example:Suppose this is the info you want to send from server and receive in onMessageReceived().

```
{
"msg":"{
"success": "true",
"groups": [{
    "groupId": "c20f2353-1f13-4ea0-8283-ghhjc4dcc725251b",
    "name": "hb",
    "description": "hjj",


}]
}"
}
```

//inside of MessageService Class. 
 //inside getData() you will have the above msg in string format.

```
if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        JsonObject jobj=new JsonObject(remoteMessage.getData());
          }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Use FCM ,GCM will not be used further

Comment: Log.d("payloadNotificationInfo:",intent.getExtras().getString("notificationinfo")); response is  -------- NotificationInfo :{"Assignment":"6","Quiz":"16","Activity":"16","Class Announcement":"4"}I Want to get result(form of)arraylist in broadcast eciver class(onRecive Method) What should i do?

Comment: else {
   String message=intent.getStringExtra("message");
   String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
   String NotificationInfo=intent.getExtras().getString("notificationInfo");
   int menu = intent.getIntExtra("menu", 0);
   CommonUtilities.saveInSP(context,"Title",title);
      CommonUtilities.saveInSP(context,"Message",message);
   CommonUtilities.saveInSP(context, "menu", menu);
//   CommonUtilities.saveInSP(context,"notificationinfo",notifications);
   CommonUtilities.saveInSP(context,"notificationInfo",NotificationInfo);

Comment: please edit your question by adding the above code..Code in comments will not be clear to understand.

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java   check this.